# How do I revert my branch to the master and throw away my commits?

Tags: git, github

We have branches `master`, `develop` and `mark`.  The `develop` branch is always the main development branch my partner works on and I use the `mark` branch to add features.

I screwed something up because after merging with `develop` my brach no longer works (currently there are no differences in `master` and `develop`).  I need to bring `mark` branch to the state of the `develop` branch and throw away my changes.  How do I do this with out removing the `mark` branch or creating a new branch?

Answer (score 3):

From the shell execute the commands to move (save) your current mark branch and create a new mark branch.

```
git checkout master
git branch -m mark mark.bad
get checkout -b mark
```

If you are absolutely determined to not create a new branch then do the following

```
git checkout master
git log -1   # copy the commit hash code to your clipboard
git checkout mark
git reset <hash code from master>
git stash save BrokenCode
```

This doesn't create a new branch.  Instead it saves the bad code to your stash and resets mark to the state of master based on the hash code of master's HEAD.